# AOP like construct with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I am looking for a simple, cheap, reliable solution to intercept method calls with objective-c 2.0. It should be possible to execute pre / post blocks and run the original method in between.

I know i can swizzle methods  - replace the IMP with something which would call the original method and allow me to exec pre / post blocks. This looks simple, is pretty fast and should work in standard cases. Any idea if there is a better - runtime magic approach - to this problem ?

PS Portability does not matter - it will run only with apples runtime on OS X and iOS.

Comment: You've stated a proposed solution rather than the actual problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Its not about a particular problem - more about solving the general case of adding pre/post code to existing methods. I used this often to inspect arguments, ret-vals, keep track of instances, log something etc. I am just not sure whats the best way to do this.

Comment: A generic alternative is to hook the `objc_msgSend` function.  An example of hooking it is [here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/source/browse/etc/objc_msgSend_hook.mm?r=472).  __builtin_* is not available under clang, so you'd have to make some tweaks there

Comment: you may want to look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508396/aspect-oriented-objective-c-library

Answer (score 0):

There is an aspect oriented approach for Objective-C:

[AspectOrientedObjectiveC](https://github.com/tomdalling/AspectObjectiveC)

I never used it and so I do not know how reliable it is.